# PHP - Using "or die()" in __construct()?

Tags: php, oop, constructor, die

I am learning OOP and PHP.

I am trying to create a class for file uploads (from here on "File"). When I create an instance of File, I want to call a function that usually succeeds, but sometimes fails (it attempts to connect to a database and create a unique value there. It tries up to 32 times).

If it fails, I don't want any functions of this File instance to work. I don't want to throw errors or anything at this time, but I want to make sure I'm aware of best practices.

Right now I have this in my __construct():

```
...
$this->id = $this->id_submit_random() or die();
...
```

After this - if id_submit_random() fails - the __construct() script stops executing on that line, and no methods or properties are accessible. The variable I would assign the class instance to would return as not belonging to that class, too. That's exactly what I want.

Basically, I want to safeguard my code from running and uploading stuff if the database is not accessible or a unique ID can't be generated.

I would like to know - is there another method of achieving this? Are there problems with this one that I'm unaware of? I don't find it in searches, so it's either ugly or problematic, or maybe I shouldn't be trying to do something like this in the first place.

Thank you.

Comment: Throwing an exception here would be much more desirable

Comment: You can raise an exception if it failed, and catch that instead.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php